# Can't start mysql server

Tags: mysql, debian

I'm facing problems installing a software package that depends on MySQL. During the installation it installs a MySQL server, but for some reason starting the services fails and thus the installation fails. I'm running a Debian 7 (64bit) virtual server, fresh installation, without plesk.

```
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

When I run `sudo -u mysql mysqld` it returns the follwing:

```
140311 20:14:12 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:12 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:12 [Warning] Using unique option prefix sort_buffer instead of sort_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:12 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
140311 20:14:12 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: Warning: innodb_file_io_threads is deprecated. Please use innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads instead
140311 20:14:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 29.6G
140311 20:14:14  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139823454459680 in file ut0mem.c line 103
InnoDB: Failing assertion: ret || !assert_on_error
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:14:14 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=10485760
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1036706 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x7f2b2faa7e59]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d8)[0x7f2b2f98f808]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030)[0x7f2b2f13e030]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f2b2d9d0475]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180)[0x7f2b2d9d36f0]
mysqld(+0x5a443b)[0x7f2b2fb1143b]
mysqld(+0x606e3a)[0x7f2b2fb73e3a]
mysqld(+0x606560)[0x7f2b2fb73560]
mysqld(+0x5bcf5f)[0x7f2b2fb29f5f]
mysqld(+0x5c3a78)[0x7f2b2fb30a78]
mysqld(+0x587235)[0x7f2b2faf4235]
mysqld(+0x5542af)[0x7f2b2fac12af]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x7f2b2f991b91]
mysqld(+0x332087)[0x7f2b2f89f087]
mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xa43)[0x7f2b2f8a22e3]
mysqld(+0x2b8c35)[0x7f2b2f825c35]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x7f2b2f8268ab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f2b2d9bcead]
mysqld(+0x2b0a39)[0x7f2b2f81da39]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
root@lvps87-230-22-117:/tmp# sudo -u mysql mysqld
140311 20:14:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix sort_buffer instead of sort_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:47 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
140311 20:14:47 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:14:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: Warning: innodb_file_io_threads is deprecated. Please use innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads instead
140311 20:14:47 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 29.6G
^[[A^[[B140311 20:14:49  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140707507746592 in file ut0mem.c line 103
InnoDB: Failing assertion: ret || !assert_on_error
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:14:49 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=10485760
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1036706 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x7ff905591e59]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d8)[0x7ff905479808]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030)[0x7ff904c28030]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7ff9034ba475]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180)[0x7ff9034bd6f0]
mysqld(+0x5a443b)[0x7ff9055fb43b]
mysqld(+0x606e3a)[0x7ff90565de3a]
mysqld(+0x606560)[0x7ff90565d560]
mysqld(+0x5bcf5f)[0x7ff905613f5f]
mysqld(+0x5c3a78)[0x7ff90561aa78]
mysqld(+0x587235)[0x7ff9055de235]
mysqld(+0x5542af)[0x7ff9055ab2af]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x7ff90547bb91]
mysqld(+0x332087)[0x7ff905389087]
mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xa43)[0x7ff90538c2e3]
mysqld(+0x2b8c35)[0x7ff90530fc35]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x7ff9053108ab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7ff9034a6ead]
mysqld(+0x2b0a39)[0x7ff905307a39]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
root@lvps87-230-22-117:/tmp# sudo -u mysql mysqld | less
root@lvps87-230-22-117:/tmp# sudo -u mysql mysqld | more
140311 20:21:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:21:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:21:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix sort_buffer instead of sort_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:21:41 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
140311 20:21:41 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140311 20:21:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: Warning: innodb_file_io_threads is deprecated. Please use innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads instead
140311 20:21:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 29.6G
140311 20:21:43  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140724219660064 in file ut0mem.c line 103
InnoDB: Failing assertion: ret || !assert_on_error
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
19:21:43 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=10485760
read_buffer_size=1048576
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=500
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1036706 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x7ffce974ae59]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d8)[0x7ffce9632808]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf030)[0x7ffce8de1030]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7ffce7673475]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x180)[0x7ffce76766f0]
mysqld(+0x5a443b)[0x7ffce97b443b]
mysqld(+0x606e3a)[0x7ffce9816e3a]
mysqld(+0x606560)[0x7ffce9816560]
mysqld(+0x5bcf5f)[0x7ffce97ccf5f]
mysqld(+0x5c3a78)[0x7ffce97d3a78]
mysqld(+0x587235)[0x7ffce9797235]
mysqld(+0x5542af)[0x7ffce97642af]
mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x41)[0x7ffce9634b91]
mysqld(+0x332087)[0x7ffce9542087]
mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xa43)[0x7ffce95452e3]
mysqld(+0x2b8c35)[0x7ffce94c8c35]
mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x45b)[0x7ffce94c98ab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7ffce765fead]
mysqld(+0x2b0a39)[0x7ffce94c0a39]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.`
```

Comment: Since H/W is mentioned as a possibility, have you run a memory tester such as memtest86+ overnight?

Comment: Did you run an apt-get install -f ? Could be that the install didn't work right.

Comment: Running with -f doesn't make any difference. I tried "apt-get install -f mysql-common" but still when i tries to start the mysql server it doesn't work. I already reinstalled the server and used a fresh installation. Same problem. Seems like this could be a configuration problem, that the software installs?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL crashed because it couldn't allocate 29.6G for the buffer pool.

"Out of memory.

We wish to hold the whole sky,

But we never will."

Comment: Agreed that 30G is rather a large default size for a DB distributed as part of a software package. But where does it say 'out of memory'? (looking at the source code, it does use an assertion to handle a failed malloc - yeuch! - http://code.google.com/p/david-mysql-tools/source/browse/branches/InnoSQL_5.5.13_flash_cache/storage/innobase/ut/ut0mem.c?r=196 )

Comment: yeah, it should have done better job in error reporting. I had to look at the source code too.